# Is there any way for me to recover or reclaim a confirmed but unspent transaction that was sent to the wrong address?

Tags: transactions

I sent money to the wrong address. I am not a developer and I only understand the blockchain in its most general terms.....but I use bitcoin everyday so I have a working knowledge of it. It's hard for me to get anywhere because I know none of the languages, anything about scripting, and can't even run a install via command prompt.....I'm working on it though. Is there a way for me to either recover, regenerate, or resend my misplaced transacrion? I see it there on blockcypher. I tried to import into one of my other wallets but it won't go because I assume I need the private key. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed Bitcoin transactions are final and cannot be undone. Try asking the receiver to send the funds back.

Edit:

If you did the transaction between accounts on an exchange, it probably can be cancelled by the exchange team.

Comment: Contact the recipient immediately, explain the mistake, and ask them to return the funds. Be sure to give them an address to return the funds to.