# Is there a way I can reach the owner of the wallet address

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

I mistakenly sent some bitcoins to a wrong address. The mistake was from the wallet address I was given. An extra letter was added, making the address 35 digits. Is there a way I can reach the owner of the wallet address I mistakenly sent it to? Please help me.

This is the wrong address that bitcoin was sent to
114dW3JX2sPPLVDnX4H8u2vsMc4CEJ3rVYf
It's a blockchain wallet.

Comment: This is, for all intents, impossible. Adding an extra character will make an address invalid. If against all odds you managed to make a single character typo and end up with a valid encoding, the address is a black hole that nobody owns.

Comment: In this particular case, any sane wallet would not create a transaction at all, and your coins should be in the address where they were before you attempted this transaction

Comment: Removing the last letter it would be a valid BTC address:
114dW3JX2sPPLVDnX4H8u2vsMc4CEJ3rVY
But it was never used so no funds ended up there. So I wonder if your coins really left your wallet.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there a way I can reach the owner of the wallet address**

No, There is no general way to find the contact details of an owner of a mistyped address. At least none that are likely to succeed for any arbitrary address.

You can check an address at any [Blockchain Explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) - this will tell you if any bitcoins were really sent there - but will not identify the identity of any person.

There are many possible valid addresses, only a very tiny few of them are in use.

If you send bitcoin to a valid address that no-one is using, those bitcoin are lost forever unless you can re-spend the inputs using a much higher fee (or miner cooperation) before your transaction is confirmed.

---

> **An extra letter was added, making the address 35 digits.**

Most wallets make it impossible or difficult to mistype an address by using a checksum.

> The probability that a mistyped address is accepted as being valid is 1 in 2<sup>32</sup>, that is, approximately 1 in 4.29 billion.

(from [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address))

`114dW3JX2sPPLVDnX4H8u2vsMc4CEJ3rVY` is a valid address but has a balance of zero and no transactions.

`114dW3JX2sPPLVDnX4H8u2vsMc4CEJ3rVYf` is not a valid address. I don't see how any Bitcoin can possibly have been sent to it.

---

> **It's a blockchain wallet.**

If your wallet shows an amount has been "spent" to that invalid address and deducted from your "balance", you should contact the company that call themselves "Blockchain Luxemburg S.A.R.L." and who presumably provide your wallet.

I recommend not using custodial wallets. See [types of Wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/81246/13866)

---

See also

- [Can a bitcoin transaction be reversed?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/197/13866)
- [Is it possible to cancel an unconfirmed transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4514/13866)
- [What happens if I mistype the address when making a payment?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/194/13866)
- [Possibly sent Bitcoin to wrong address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/64195/13866)
- [Is there any way for me to recover or reclaim a confirmed but unspent transaction that was sent to the wrong address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/42801/13866)